# Is it possible to use monitor presets in Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, settings, 20.10

I use Ubuntu 20.10. I have 2 scenarios of using monitors. For example the first scenario is using laptop display and external monitor. The second one - is to use only external monitor plugged to the laptop. So every time I swap the scenarios I manually set up its settings(such as main display, display mode, positions of displays) again, which is quite inconvenient procedure. So is it possible somehow to save this scenarios and every time I wand to swap it, I only need to choose one that I want or create the new one. Maybe there are some tools that can solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not a GNOME user so I don't know if there are great & easy ways.  I will say I'd *hacked* a script that worked in multiple desktops (I use a number but not GNOME often) that allowed me to automatically use a laptop when plugged into various docks (*one where the external monitor was on the left [of laptop], another with the monitor to the right; ie. a script that quickly setup for the different desks I sat at*).  I considered it a *hack* but it worked for me (*shortcuts allowed me to run it via mouse/menu, or I'd ctrl+alt+T & run from CLI usually*)  *but I didn't try wayland or gnome*

Comment: @guiverc, could you please share the script?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure where it is. The laptop stopped being used a couple of years ago,  (replaced with a desktop) and whilst I'm sure it'd still work with XFCE/LXDE (worked with MATE too) etc; I can't even know if it was ever tried on LXQt (that replaced LXDE in 18.10) let alone GNOME you want it for.  If I find it I'll provide

Comment: An example of a command to setup maybe `xrandr --output VGA-0 --off --output DVI-0 --mode 1280x1024 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-0 --primary --mode 1280x1024 --pos 1280x0 --rotate left`   (the script would have been a shell around two of these commands (one for each setup) though I don't recall have landscape+portrait)  .. hopefully you'll see what this does & adjust to get what you want